# python help('modules') returns ImportError

Tags: python, pip, package-management

Recently, (I have **no** idea when), I installed this package called pymol. Today when I was trying to copy a list of all my install modules, I encountered this error.

```
~/Projects$ python -c "help('modules')"
Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

Error: unable to initalize the pymol.cmd module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymol/cmd.py", line 117, in <module>
    from chempy import io
ImportError: cannot import name io
```

I've tried

```
sudo pip uninstall pymol
```

This definitely worked... but it also definitely did not work. It removed the .egg, and pip list tells me it's not installed, but the tool is still there. I open a python prompt and import it with no problem. Now my question is, if I just delete the package, is there anything that could go wrong, (WCS I'm thinking kafkaesque broken dependency fixing for the rest of my natural life.) and is there a standardized, best practice to remove this, or any other package manually.

Comment: If you can import it even if it's not there, that could mean (a) you installed it in some weird way behind `pip`'s back and confused it, (b) you had one copy in your user site-packages and one in your system site-packages, and removing one didn't remove the other, or (c) you have two different Python installations, and the `pip` on your path is from one, the `python` on the other, so you didn't actually remove it (from the relevant Python) at all.

Comment: By the way, if you're on a Mac, and you installed Python 2.7, then you do have two installations, because Apple already gave you one. And since Apple's doesn't come with `pip`, unless you manually installed it, it's not that uncommon that you have the third-party Python's `pip` first on your path, but Apple's `python` first on your path.

Comment: I'm running python2.7 on a linux box, with the default installation that came with the OS.

Comment: yes, /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymol/ contains a .pyc for every .py file.

Comment: I just saw the dir is still there, what does `which -a python` output from bash?

Comment: `which -a python` = `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: ok so def just the default linux install. You installed with pip yes?

Comment: Yeah, and `file /usr/bin/python` says it's just a soft link to python2.7, Nothing weird there.

Comment: This is strange. There was a file named `_cmd.so`, (is it common for a python program to generate shared object, did I miss that somewhere?) in the tradition of 'one of these things is not like the other', I deleted it and after I deleted it, `help('modules')` ran without the `ImportError`. I guess because it started with an underscore a `from  pymol import *` would have skipped it. I'm moving on, but I'd still like to have the last part of my initial question answered.

Comment: `_cmd.so` is  compiled `c` or `c++`, lots of python modules use .so files.