# Why use quotes in help('modules'') in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter

While trying out the Python interactive help, I noticed we need to use quotes around "modules" when trying to see a list of all available modules in python interpreter.

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.195]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\amber>python
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help('modules')
```

But, we don't need to use the quotes when trying to read help of an object; eg -

```
>>> help(tuple)
```

Why is this difference?

I tried to find the answer by repeated Google searches as well as searching the Stack Overflow but the closest question were about [returning some errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213533/python-helpmodules-returns-importerror) or not [addressing the quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36242211/missing-module-links-in-python-using-help), while question in [other websites](http://learni.online/all/Why_do_we_use_quotes_in_help(%27modules%27)_in_Python_interpreter) don't have any answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`modules` is not a built-in class in Python, whereas tuple is. In fact, you can wrap quotes around anything when using `help`. This is perfectly valid:

```
help("tuple")
```

However, the reason we don't need to is because by doing `help(tuple)`, we're passing in a class to `help`, so what `help` will do is give us information about such class.

Note that if you type `help(modules)` you'll see that modules isn't defined - it's not a built-in class.

Answer (score 1):

"If string is passed as an argument, name of a module, function, class, method, keyword, or documentation topic, and a help page is printed."
See: [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/help)